# java.lang.IllegalStateException: LifecycleProcessor not initialized - call 'refr esh' before invoking lifecycle methods via the context

Tags: java, tomcat

1. when add project to the eclipse server(tomcat 7.0.52), it starts with no error
2. when export the project into war file, and deploy it on tomcat 7.0.52, it starts with error as title
3. jdk version is 1.8.0_31, sonarqube must starts with jdk > 1.8
4. the pictures below shows the jar file version

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rpDLP.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TAkfg.png)

Answer (score 1):

try adding this dependency

```
 <dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
     <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
 </dependency>
```

or

it might happen if you are using some external jars outside your **pom.xml**

or 
    you can also try changing your jdk to 1.7